# What does the symbol represent?

Tags: notepad++

I'm generating a text file, which later on I have to upload to an fpt which runs a web service, which processes my file. It seems the separator I use (space) is not the one required, therefore I need your help identifying what symbol is the one Notepad++ shows when using "Show All Characters" option:

[image]

I'd like to know what is the equivalent symbol for the small "arrow", because the second longer "arrow" represents the Tab symbol and the small "dot" between date and time is the space symbol.

Comment: At a guess, it's still Tab, but going to a different tabstop (note how it's 4 characters back than the larger ones at the next tabstop).  Can you copy and paste it into something like this: http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html - should tell you.

Comment: When I hit tab I see four dots like "...." (except the dots are like mid character height.  Anyone know why I don't get the arrow when I hit tab?

Answer (score 10):

It's a tab. The length of the arrow varies, because a tab tries to fill as many spaces as are needed to reach the next multiple of 4 (or your chosen value of number of spaces in a tab).

So in your case I suppose 1 tab is 4 spaces (which is the default), and at line 1 you have 7 characters before the tab (`RTC2040`), so the arrow is just one character long (so that it leads to position 8), but at the last lines you have 9 characters (`20_RUD360`), so you need 3 to reach a multiple of 4 (in this case 12) and the arrow is longer.

Comment: When I press tab in Notepad++ I get a series of 4 dots instead of a long arrow. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @user9964422 Go to Settings -> Preferences, choose "Language" from the left column, and in the right column you'll see that you have selected "Replace by space". Unselect it and you will get a tab.

Answer (score 5):

This is is the `tab` character. As you can see, it is retracted because the space of a tabulation is fixed.

Enters are the little <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> marks, `NULL` characters are <kbd>NUL</kbd>, spaces are orange dots on blank spaces... <kbd>ACK</kbd> for Acknowledge characters, and so on..